# gcloud multiple terminals with different configuration active

Tags: gcloud, gcloud-cli

I work with different environments Staging and production. Typically I need to do things at same time in both environments. Each environment is a gcloud configuration. So I'm always jumping between configurations.

**I would like to have different configuration activated in different terminals, is there any way?**

When I ran the command bellow, it affect all the terminal, is there any way to affect only the current terminal?

```
gcloud config configurations activate <config-name>
```

**Any workaround idea would be also useful**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According `gcloud help`:

```
GLOBAL FLAGS
     ...
     --configuration=CONFIGURATION
        The configuration to use for this command invocation. For more
        information on how to use configurations, run: gcloud topic
        configurations. You can also use the [CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME]
        environment variable to set the equivalent of this flag for a terminal
        session.
```

You could run in one terminal

```
export CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=config-name1
```

and in another terminal

```
export CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=config-name2
```

Hope that's useful.